# this_thread::sleep_for affecting other thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, future

I have a simple program with two threads, one that pushes a `packaged_task` into a `deque`, and other that executes it. In the tasks there is a `this_thread::sleep_for`, and I would expect that only the "process" thread would wait for it, but both are waiting, making the execution sequential. What I'm missing?

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>

std::mutex m;
std::condition_variable cv;
std::deque<std::packaged_task<void(int)>> deque;

void post() {
    int id = 0;
    auto lambda = [](int id) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(std::rand() % 10 + 1)); 
        std::cout << id << std::endl;
    };
    while (true) {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

        std::packaged_task<void(int)> task(lambda);
        task(id++);

        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lg(m);
        deque.emplace_back(std::move(task));

        cv.notify_one();
    }
}

void process() {
    std::deque<std::packaged_task<void(int)>> to_exec;
    while (true) {

        while (!to_exec.empty()){
            std::future<void> fut = to_exec.front().get_future();
            fut.get();

            to_exec.pop_front();
        }

        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(m);
        cv.wait(lk, []() {return !deque.empty(); });

        while (!deque.empty()) {
            to_exec.push_back(std::move(deque.front()));
            deque.pop_front();
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    std::thread tpost(post);
    std::thread tprocess(process);

    tpost.join();
    tprocess.join();
}
```

Comment: A `packaged_task` is not asynchronous in itself. It can be passed to a thread constructor since it's callable, but there's no background thread being created for you automatically. Perhaps you want [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) with a `std::launch::async` [launch policy](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch)?

Comment: Why do you call `task(id++);` in `post` immediately after creating `task`?  Isn't the intention to bind the value of `id` so that it's passed as the parameter when the lambda is eventually invoked?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude good point. I'll try that.

Comment: @G.M. you mean creating like `task(std::bind(lambda,id++))` ? I thought both ways would be equivalent... I guess I have to review the documentation more carefuly. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think more effective will be use [std::async](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/future/async/) instead a sleeping random seconds...